# Compile Angular Project only on Save

Tags: json, angular

Currently my Angular project compiles on save and whenever there is a code change. I would like it such that it only compiles on a save.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn of the **`autoSave`** feature.

To Change:

```
File > Preferences > Settings > Search autoSave > select off
```

User Settings after change:

```
"files.autoSave": "off",
```

Comment: This answer assumes the OP is using VS Code, yet there is no mention of an IDE in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run `ng serve --watch=false` if you don't want it to watch for changes.